# How to use cap to run `npm install` and `npm run bundle` (which should be the same as `webpack`) on server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, webpack, capistrano

I'm currently trying to deploy my rails project to servers. My rails project use `npm` and `webpack` instead of the existing rails asset pipeline, but I don't know how to use `cap` to run `npm install` and `npm run bundle` (which should be the same as `webpack`) on the server.

Basically, I need to change the following into Capistrano's way of doing things:

1) `npm install`

If working locally, I would do `cd lib/assets`, then do `npm install`

2) Run webpack to compile the asset

If working locally, I would do `npm run bundle` while in the `lib/assets` folder, because inside `lib/assets/package.json`, I have a script called `bundle` which runs `webpack`, the `lib/assets/package.json` file contains this:

```
"bundle": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
```

I'm thinking about writing a task in `lib/capistrano/tasks/precompile.rake` to do this. It will be something like:

```
namespace :assets do
  desc 'run npm install and npm run bundle'
  task :precompile do
    on roles(:web), in: :parallel do |server|
      within release_path do
        execute "cd lib/assets; npm install; npm run bundle"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The above are just pseudo code, and I have many question about it but struggle to find answer using Google, so I decide to make this post here.

The questions I have are:

1) I have 2 servers, should I really run `npm run bundle -p` on both server? Or should I just change role and run on one server only?

2) Is `execute :npm, "install"` really valid? I write it because I saw some other coder wrote `execute :bundle, 'exec rake assets:precompile'`

3) After `npm run bundle` (which triggers webpack) is ran and has compile the asset, I want to close it instead of letting it keep running. Is there a command that is better suited for this? (that don't keep run forever, and just run one off)

Comment: what do you mean by 2 servers, are you trying to deploy the same application to 2 different servers ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right